# ERROR: While writing data in MySQL using External Writable Table with PXF

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jvm, connector, greenplum

We are trying to migrate the table from Greenplum 6.8 (open-source) to MySQL (5.7.28) using External Writable Table with PXF (version 5.11.2) service we are getting the below error in "pxf-service.log":

ERROR:
"the exception contained within the mappable container exception could not be mapped to a response re throwing to the HTTP container java IO exception invalid chunk header."

Is anyone help us out in the Migration of the table from Greenplum to MySQL with a Writable external table option with PXF service.

Comment: Hi Azeem, can you provide the stacktrace in the PXF log files associated with this error. What is the size of the data you are trying to export to MySQL?

Comment: Hi @frankgh, these are the error messages we have in the PXF log file:

ERROR: "the exception contained within the mappable container exception could not be mapped to a response re throwing to the HTTP container java IO exception invalid chunk header."

Secondly, the table size was 184GB on the source (Greenplum database).

Comment: Also, in addition, some of the rows(records) have been transferred from Greenplum to the MySQL side but not all the data. In between the error was thrown.

Comment: it's possible that you are using connection pooling to access MySQL (the default) and it's possible that not all the segments are able to get a connection within 30 seconds. I would need to look at your PXF logs located under `$PXF_CONF/logs` to better debug the issue, but I'm suspecting that the issue is related to this issue: `java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException`. You can increase the number of connections to the external database in your `jdbc-site.xml` configuration by increasing the `jdbc.pool.property.maximumPoolSize` property to match the number of segments per host you have.